# Google Play does not install applications through OpenVPN connect

Tags: google-play-store, openvpn

Google Play works fine as application browser, but fails to install any app when OpenVPN is active. The same problem repeats on 3 phones from different vendors.

How to investigate?

Comment: Where is the OpenVNP server located (on network level). Is the Internet freely accessible from the OpenVPN server (e.g. any deep-inspection man-in-the-middle proxies active in this network)?

Comment: Aruba.it VPS in CZ domain. I know nothing about any DPI and MITM but I have never (during 2 years) met any problems with access to any service using this server.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the "How to investigate?":

1. Enable ADB (Android debugging) on your phone.

   - Go to settings -> about this phone (or similar naming) and press the "Build number" 7 times. Congratulations, you are now a developer!
   - Go to settings -> Developer Options. Enable "Android debugging"
2. Connect your phone to a PC and install adb on there.

   - On debian based Linux: `apt-get install adb`
   - On arch based Linux: `pacman -S adb`
   - Please see Google "How to install adb on *YOUR_OS*" for other Operating Systems
3. Open a terminal on your PC (On Windows, make sure you are in the same directory as the `adb` binary. You might need to replace the `adb` below with `./adb` or `./adb.exe` on Windows.)
4. Run `adb devices` to make sure your phone shows up. Confirmation on phone might be required.
5. Run `adb shell` to get a shell into your phone.
6. Within that shell, run `logcat *:W` (without the `*:W` for more verbosity).

You will now get a lot of log entries, the `*:W` shows only warnings and "worse". Without disconnecting USB or closing the shell, try to get something from the Play Store now. Watch the log window on your PC. Try to look for anything related in there.

My guess is that Google simply blocks downloads from your VPN (logcat should show this clearly), so have this workaround aswell:

**Install F-Droid**

[F-Droid](https://f-droid.org) is an alternative App Store that has a lot of really nice open source applications.

**But I want an app that isn't on F-Droid**

Check out [Yalp Store](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.github.yeriomin.yalpstore/) on F-droid!

I personally do not use Google services and removed everything Google from my phone. Nor do I have a Google account. Whenever I do need an application that's only on the Play Store though, I use Yalp. You don't need an account, you can browse apps just like in the Play Store and they install just as easily. It's kinda like a proxy to the Play Store. APKs are being downloaded from Google, not some fishy weird websites, so it's safe to use.

Depending on how Yalp works exactly, it might try to access the APK from Google's servers using your IP, which means it might still get blocked. But it's most certainly worth a try and might very well work!